# Problema al castear variables en Java : NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, android

Estaba empezando con Android, pero al realizar algo que en Java nunca me ha dado problemas y al lanzarlo en una App de Android, me han saltado bastantes errores al ejecutarlo, porque compilar lo hace sin problemas.

El ejercicio que intento realizar es una calculador muy simple, cojo dos valores de dos TextView distintos, los suma y muestra en una pantalla el resultado.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void calcularResultado(View view) {

        TextView cuadroNum1, cuadroNum2, resultado;

        cuadroNum1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tNum1);
        cuadroNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tNum2);
        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);


        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, aux;


        num1 = Integer.parseInt(cuadroNum1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(cuadroNum2.getText().toString());

        resultado.setText(String.format(""+ (num1 + num2) ));
    }
}
```

Después de hacer varias pruebas me di cuenta que la aplicación se cerraba al emularla con los casteos, tal y como se puede ver en el código.

No sé si en Android no se pueden realizar así los casteos, porque los TextView devuelven "Char Sequences", pero pasarlos a `String` no da errores hasta que intento pasarlos a variables de tipo `int`, o si debería usar otro elemento alternativo al TextView si quiero trabajar con dígitos.

Código el error:

```
       --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.pabloperezaradros.calculadora, PID: 2740
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                      at com.pabloperezaradros.calculadora.MainActivity.calcularResultado(MainActivity.java:26)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: La operación debe ir entre parentesis internamente creo como en Java `resultado.setText(String.format(""+ (num1 + num2)));`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ya he editado ese fallo. Mi problema principal es que el emulador me falla al usar el Integer.parseInt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes este problema al llamar el método `onClick()` teniendo lo siguiente como el principal problema:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Y **ocurre cuando intentas convertir un valor string no numerico a `int`, en este caso un string vacio, `""`.**

Puedes usar una función para comprobar primeramente si el valor es numerico para posteriormente usar `Integer.parseInt()` para realizar la conversión :

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String valor) {
 try {
double d = Double.parseDouble(valor); 
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
return false; 
} 
return true;
 }
```

En base al método anterior podemos usar una operación ternaria para realizar la conversión:

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, aux;
num1 = isNumeric(cuadroNum1.getText().toString())? Integer.parseInt(cuadroNum1.getText().toString()):0 ; 
num2 = isNumeric(cuadroNum2.getText().toString())? Integer.parseInt(cuadroNum2.getText().toString()):0 ;
```

Cuando el valor no sea númerico el resultado será 0, tu puedes definir el valor default.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, a mi programa no le he pasado nada que no sean números. Lo que me propones me ayuda a gestionar el error, no a resolverlo. Mi intención es coger int de esos textview. Si no puedo castearlos igual tengo que usar otros campos.

Comment: El error que tienes * Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" * es causado porque **intentas convertir un string vacio a entero. ** No entiendo porque dices que esto ayuda a gestionarlo y no a resolverlo

Comment: Porque con tu método evitas que salte el error, y está muy bien planteado, pero sigue sin solucionar el porque no coge el contenido de los textview y los castea, porque aunque la excepcón diga que el campo está vacio en mi programa siempre introduzco valores y aun así da el mismo error y ya he comprobado si coge bien la cadena (que si la coge) de los textview simplemente falla al realizar el casteo aunque no se muy bien porque. De todas formas ya lo solucioné usando campos editText. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Las operaciones internas con números enteros deben ir entre paréntesis, como en Java. además debe declarar sus componentes en el método onCreate

```
TextView cuadroNum1, cuadroNum2, resultado;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cuadroNum1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tNum1);
    cuadroNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tNum2);
    resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
}

 public void calcularResultado(View view) {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, aux;
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(cuadroNum1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(cuadroNum2.getText().toString());

    resultado.setText(String.format(""+ (num1 + num2) ));


 }
```

Comment: vale gracias, no me había dado cuenta, pero aun así el problema me da en el Integer.parseInt y nose muy bien por qué.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tu respuesta, he probado también el valueOf y sigue crasheando la aplicación, he actualizado la pregunta con los errores de la aplicación. Un saludo.

Comment: Verificar mi Respuesta, declarar tus variables antes del Método `onCreate()` y dentro de él Inicializar dichas variables.

Comment: Nada de nada, sigue sin funcionar igualmente

Answer (score 0):

Agrega esto bueno estoy usando 2 EditText, 1 TextView(resultado)
 y 1 Button

```
public class ejemplo extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editorTexto1, editorTexto2;
private TextView vistaTexto;
private Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ejemplo_activity);
    editorTexto1    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editorTexto2    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    vistaTexto      = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    boton           = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calcularResultado();
        }
    });
}

public void calcularResultado() {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, resultado = 0;

    num1 = Integer.parseInt(editorTexto1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(editorTexto1.getText().toString());
    resultado = num1 + num2;

    vistaTexto.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
}}
```

Comment: El problema era por el TextView, ahora me funciona perfectamente. Muchas Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Que problema tenia el TextView? *No entiendo como se soluciono con un textview!!! =0

Comment: No se cuál era el problema pero con el mismo planteamiento simplemente con usar  editText en vez de TextView funcionó correctamente.

Comment: Pablo de nada, sigue en tu camino ninja =)
@Elenasys se soluciona si inicializa el textview con cualquier número (en este caso 0, ya no tendría una excepción)