# Android Studio... "La aplicación se ha detenido" : java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, android

Hola amigos quería ver si me podrían apoyar con este pequeño error que me salta al ejecutar mi aplicacion...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText dato;
    private TextView resultado;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dato = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_datos);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);

        if(dato.getText().toString().length()==0){
            resultado.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ingresa un valor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    //lo que debería hacer este if es mostrar un aviso para que ingrese algo en el campo vacío
    }

    //Procedimiento que realiza la conversion de Celsius a Fahrenheit

    public void convF(View view) {

        String valor = dato.getText().toString();
        float  number = Float.parseFloat(valor);
        float conversion1 = ((number*9/5)+32);


            }

            String res = Float.toString(conversion1);

            resultado.setText(res + "°F");
        }
    }
```

El error que arroja el Logcat es este...

```
2019-09-13 22:59:23.894 18763-18763/com.example.conversordetemperaturas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.conversordetemperaturas, PID: 18763
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
        at com.example.conversordetemperaturas.MainActivity.convF(MainActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Lo que pasa es que realmente compila, y hace lo que tiene que hacer (convertir de celsius a fahrenheit), pero el problema esta en que al presionar el boton "Convertir a Fahrenheit" se cierra la aplicacion.
Quería ver si podrían ayudar a solucionar este problema para que la aplicación no se cierre al presionar el boton sin que haya nada.
Cualquier ayuda de verdad se agradece, saludos!

Comment: Es necesario que agregues que error te arroja en el Logcat, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mensaje.

Comment: Me aparecen todos esos errores...

Answer (score 0):

El error se encuentra en la linea numero `32` de tu `MainActivity` e indica que la cadena que intenta analizar esta vacia, lo conveniente seria agregar tu validación dentro del envento click de tu boton.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText dato;
    private TextView resultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dato = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_datos);
        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    }

    //Procedimiento que realiza la conversion de Celsius a Fahrenheit
    public void convF(View view) {
        //lo que debería hacer este if es mostrar un aviso para que ingrese algo en el campo vacío
        if (dato.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            resultado.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ingresa un valor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String valor = dato.getText().toString();
            float number = Float.parseFloat(valor);
            float conversion1 = ((number * 9 / 5) + 32);

            String res = Float.toString(conversion1);
            resultado.setText(res + "°F");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica en el `LogCat`

> IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

**al tratar de llamar el método `convF()` mediante el clic a un botón este trata de realizar la conversión de una cadena a numérico, pero en este caso el valor es una cadena vacía, por esta razón se produce el error `NumberFormatException`!**

Para esto te aconsejo validar el valor que se obtiene de el `EditText` dato.

Revisa:

[Problema al castear variables en Java (Android) : NumberFormatException: For input string: ""](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26677/problema-al-castear-variables-en-java-android-numberformatexception-for-inp/26698#26698)

---

La mejor solución es validar si el contenido del `EditText` es numérico, agrega otro método que valide si el contenido del `EditText` dato es numérico, en caso de que el valor no sea numérico este retornará el valor predeterminado 0.

De esta forma se evitará que tu  aplicación se cierre.

```
    public static float validaValor(String valor) {
        float f = 0;
        try {
            f = Float.parseFloat(valor);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error");
        }
        return f;
    }



 public void convF(View view) {

        //String valor = dato.getText().toString();            
        float  number = validaValor(valor);//Float.parseFloat(valor);
        float conversion1 = ((number*9/5)+32);


            }

            String res = Float.toString(conversion1);

            resultado.setText(res + "°F");
        }
    }
```